# Late notifications on Background Service

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service, notifications

I'm doing a simple service that, every 10 minutes, download a WebPage (The HTML code), and notify the user if something is changed. Now, the problem is that the first 3-4 notifications are shown correctly, but after these, there's an important delay between notifications, and sometimes they don't arrive.
Here's my code:
**Monitor.java**

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    customHandler = new android.os.Handler();
    customHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);


}

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        RUN = true;


        LINK = readMessage("ADDR");

        Ion.with(getApplicationContext()).load(LINK).asString().setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                Risultad = result;

                if (fileExists(getApplicationContext(), "AVV") == false)

                {
                    Savefile(Risultad, "AVV");
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                            getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    NotificationCompat.Builder n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setContentTitle("First")
                            .setContentText(Risultad.toString())
                            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                            .setVibrate(new long[]{2000})
                            .setContentIntent(pi)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email);
                    notificationManager.notify(0, n.build());
                }
                if (fileExists(getApplicationContext(), "AVV") == true)

                {
                    final String OldAvv = readMessage("AVV");


                    if (Risultad.equals(OldAvv + "\r\n") == false) {

                        Savefile(result, "AVV");
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);
                        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                                getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        NotificationCompat.Builder n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                .setContentTitle("Something happened")
                                .setContentText(result.toString())
                                .setContentIntent(pi)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email);
                        notificationManager.notify(0, n.build());

                    }
                }


            }


        });
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 300000);
    }
```

I'm using the Ion library to download the page.
readMessage, SaveFile and fileExist are used to read,save or check my HTML code stored on the device.

Sometimes, the notifications are shown when I open the app.

What can I do to receive the notifications on time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

> These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future. When an alarm goes off, the Intent that had been registered for it is broadcast by the system, automatically starting the target application if it is not already running. Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time), but will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted.
>
> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.

See [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) for more info and code examples

Comment: Yes, I saw, but I don't understand how to use it with a BroadcastReceiver on Boot Completed

Comment: I added a link to the answer with some code examples. In a BroadcastReceiver listening to the boot completed intent, you could reset the alarm using the methods from AlarmManager, such as setRepeating, setInexactRepeating, etc.